# Docker can't reach localhost applications

Tags: azure, docker

I'm having a server with an self hosted Azure DevOps agent.
This agent is running a docker container with `docker run --rm --network host` parameters. This docker image can't reach localhost addresses on the server itself. How can I fix that? Is the network mode maybe wrong? Or do I need to add extra settings on the Azure DevOps agent?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

Each Docker container has its own loopback address (127.0.0.1). So, if you are trying to access localhost inside the container then it will access its own loopback address instead of the host machine (where your docker engine is running).

You can do two things as far I know:

1. Bind host machine ports with container ports

   `127.0.0.1:80:80`
2. Use your host machine IP address.

> Instead of using localhost inside your docker container to access your
> host machine, use the IP address.

Comment: `--network host` disables the container's network namespace.